# Importing function definitions from a bash script w/o running it

Tags: bash, shell

I have two scripts foo.sh and bla.sh

foo.sh

```
#bin/bash 
test(){
    "hello world"
}   
test
exit 1
```

bla.sh

```
#bin/bash 
source ./a.sh
echo a.test
```

The problem is that source seems like run the a.sh script, and of course then after exit 1 b never is executed.

There´s any way to just use the function test from bla without run the whole script?

Comment: Aside: `.sh` implies that a script is intended to be sourced into a POSIX sh script, whereas a `#!/bin/bash` shebang indicates execution by bash, not POSIX sh. If you mean something to be sourced by another shell instance, use an extension that accurately indicates *which* shell is supported.

Comment: (...whereas if something is intended to only be a command and not be sourced, it shouldn't have any extension at all, just as you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`).

Comment: Further aside: A shebang has to be `#!/bin/bash`; `#bin/bash` won't work -- `#!` have to be the first two characters or the operating system won't acknowledge the shebang as such.

Comment: (also, since `test` is a shell builtin, it's good practice to name anything that overlaps something difference, hence `mytest` in my example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want your script to be capable of being sourced without running its contents, you should design it that way.

```
#!/bin/bash

# put your function definitions here
mytest() { echo "hello world"; }

# ...and choose one of the following, depending on your requirements:

# more reliable approach, *except* doesn't detect being sourced from an interactive or
# piped-in shell.
(( ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} > 1 )) && return

# less reliable approach in general, but *does* detect being sourced from an interactive
# shell.
[[ "$BASH_SOURCE" != "$0" ]] && return

# put your actions to take when executed here
mytest
exit 1
```

---

#### Why it works: `(( ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} > 1 ))`

If the array of source files (per stack frame) is of length more than one in the *root* of a script, the only way to have any additional stack frame is for the script to have been sourced from elsewhere.

The caveat, here, is that an interactive shell (or a noninteractive shell with its input coming from a pipeline or other non-file source) doesn't have an entry in the `BASH_SOURCE` array, so if we're sourced from a human-driven shell -- or a shell reading its input from a pipeline or other non-file source -- there will still be only one entry.

#### Why it works: `[[ $BASH_SOURCE != "$0" ]]`

`BASH_SOURCE` is an array of source files, one element per stack frame; like all bash arrays, when expanded without explicitly indexing into a specific element, it defaults to the first one (that being the file currently being executed *or sourced*). `$0` is the name of the command being executed, which *is not* updated by the `source` command.

Thus, if these don't match, we know that we were sourced.

**Important caveat:**
Note that there are circumstances where depending on `$0` will necessarily be broken: `cat input-script | bash` can't accurately know the location on disk where `input-script` came from, so it will always detect this as being sourced. See the *Why $0 is NOT an option* section of [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) to understand these limitations in detail.

Comment: Can you explain me please what that means this "[[ $_ != $0 ]] && return # being sourced" Regards

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Do you know what `[[ ]]` does? `&&`? `$0`? `$_`?

Comment: Sorry very very newby on bash. I only understand the && and I´m not even sure what it´s doing in this context. Really sorry.

Comment: `[[ $foo = "$bar" ]]` is a string comparison. (`[[ $foo = $bar ]]` is not, quite -- it treats the right-hand side as a glob expression, as opposed to a string -- but it's close). `&&` is a short-circuiting boolean operator, same as it is in most other languages: Because it's short-circuiting, the right-hand side only runs if the left-hand side has a truthy result. And when a script is being sourced, `return` exits it early.

Comment: Unfortunately `$0` isn't all that reliable (even `bash` from where that quote comes from doesn't actually *do* that,  it doesn't use an absolute pathname it uses whatever you typed to run the script, that still happens to match but that's coincidental).

Comment: @EtanReisner, I'm well aware, and have been working on rewriting this answer with something more reliable. :)

Comment: In `ksh` at least just using `return` in the script would work (as `ksh` allows that from directly run scripts though `bash` does not).

Comment: @EtanReisner, the just-`return` approach *can* be used in bash, but it throws an ugly error in the execution case.

Comment: Right and returns `1` instead of the desired error.

Comment: @EtanReisner, ...what's your take on quality of this as-amended?

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. I wonder if there's anything to be gained by checking for `i` in `$-` with the `> 1` test that would improve it without needing to drop back to `$0` but I don't know if that will be reliable enough to worth it (in the face of it getting things wrong the other way for `bash -i script.sh`, etc.). Does the `= $0` test false-positive? If not using both options would be slightly more robust than just the first one in closing *some* of the interactive shell (and possibly all for `bash`) "holes".

Comment: I haven't actually found any cases where `$BASH_SOURCE = $0` will false-positive, but also have only a limited amount of trust for it -- haven't tested cases where the access path and absolute path to a source file differ, for instance.